# PHP: Combining Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have these 2 arrays coming from 2 separate SQL statements.

1st array:

```
$a1 = array(
    array('referral_count' => 213),
    array('referral_count' => 88),
    array('referral_count' => 35)
);
```

2nd array:

```
$a2 = array(
    array('ocean_company_id' => 524, 'customer_company_id' => 522),
    array('ocean_company_id' => 527, 'customer_company_id' => 522),
    array('ocean_company_id' => 544, 'customer_company_id' => 543)
);
```

Now what I want to do is combine both arrays to become:

```
$a3 = array(
    array(
        'ocean_company_id' => 524,
        'customer_company_id' => 522,
        'referral_count' => 213),
    array(
        'ocean_company_id' => 527,
        'customer_company_id' => 522,
        'referral_count' => 88),
    array(
        'ocean_company_id' => 544,
        'customer_company_id' => 543,
        'referral_count' => 35)
);
```

I tried `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive` but it is appending to the array instead of combining it. Thanks!

PS. I have other arrays I want to combine as well, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Before going the PHP side, could the SQL be combined into one query?

Comment: Sadly it can not be combined :( I already tried that route since there are a lot more other data needed from the main SQL statement.

Comment: I have 1 main SQL statement which extracts the different ids, and inside my while loop I need the ids to query to other tables to get the other data/counts. thus the need to combine the results into 1 array.

Comment: [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) doesn't work because your arrays have numeric keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a buffer. Suppose your arrays have the same length.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $i => $arr)
{
    $result[$i] = array_merge($arr, $array2[$i]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here's a kind of weird way to add the values from the first array to the second array.

```
for ($i=0; isset($a1[$i]); $a2[$i]['referral_count'] = $a1[$i]['referral_count'], $i++);
```

This is basically the same thing as

```
$i = 0;
while (isset($a1[$i])) {
    $a2[$i]['referral_count'] = $a1[$i]['referral_count'];
    $i++;
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that there are no function calls and no additional variables are created (except `$i`);

If you don't want to change your input arrays, you can use `array_map` with `array_merge` to combine them into a new array:

```
$a3 = array_map('array_merge', $a2, $a1);
```

The advantage to this approach is that, because both of these functions take a variable number of arguments, you can combine as many arrays as you like.

Comment: fastest solution : $a3 = array_map('array_merge', $a2, $a1);